# Select multiple row where one of their columns is the same

Tags: sql, python-3.x

i wanna select a row where in another row with same userid is Active . like :

mytable

| userid | userfield | fieldstatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Tom |
| 1 | account | Active |
| 2 | name | Jerry |
| 2 | account | Failed |

I want to select tom in name user  field where its account is active . I'm writing in python

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `exists`:

```
select t.fieldstatus from mytable t where t.userfield = "name" and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.userid = t.userid and t1.userfield = "account" and t1.fieldstatus = "Active")
```

Output

| fieldstatus |
| --- |
| Tom |

Answer (score 0):

You can check the same userid value using `exists`

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists (
  select * from mytable t2
  where t2.userid=t.userid
    and t2.userfield='account' 
    and t2.fieldstatus='Active'
```

)